# Force derived class to implement interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface, enums

I am here today (like yesterday) with another weird interface question.

I have a class:

```
public class InputDevice<T> where T : Button {

    protected List<T> buttons = new List<T>();

    protected InputDevice() {
        //Only allow instanciation from within a derived class
    }
}
```

As you can see, this class cannot be instantiated. 
A class that derives from it might be able to be instantiated.

This is a subclass:

```
public sealed class Keyboard : InputDevice<KeyboardButton> {

    public Keyboard() {
        buttons.Add(new KeyboardButton(KeyCode.A));
    }
}
```

So far so good.
Now I'd like all derivers of `InputDevice<T>` to provide a `GetButton()` method.
That method should take in the enum-Type of the Device's buttons as an argument.
**For the `Keyboard` class it would look like this:**

```
public KeyBoardButton GetButton(KeyCode Code) {
    //Retrieve button
}
```

**For the `Mouse : InputDevice<MouseButton>` it would look like:**

```
public MouseButton GetButton(MouseButtons Button) {
    //Retrieve button
}
```

*Note: `MouseButton (class) != MouseButtons (enum)`*

Each deriver of `InputDevice(T)` must implement that method.
But I don't want the `InputDevice(T)` itself to implement it because it doesn't know the enum-type of the Buttons (f.e. KeyCode). 
It just knows the type of the Buttons, which is T.

1. **Solution**

Adding the following interface to `InputDevice(T)`

```
public interface IInputDevice{
    void GetButton(System.Type);
}
```

- **Problem:**

`InputDevice(T`) has to implement it, which it can not.
I do not know the return type `T` of `InputDevice(T)`

2. **Solution:**

Adding the method manually in all derivers.

- **Problem:**

Derivers are not guaranteed to provide the methods.

---

Do you have a solution for this? I got really confused while trying to sort this out.

Comment: If you don't want the class to be instanciated directly why don't you use an `abstract` class? This would be the standard way to do this.

Comment: You say `GetButton` but return type is void :\

Comment: When it comes to *Derivers are not guaranteed to provide the methods.*. The answer is: yes they are, they just don't have to do anything in the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force sub classes to implement a method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771741/how-to-force-sub-classes-to-implement-a-method)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You mean in the interface? Yes, as said - the interface does not know the return type T. That is why this solution does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make the base class abstract and change its definition to include the key code type:

```
public abstract class InputDevice<TButton, TEnum> where TButton : Button {
    public abstract TButton GetButton(TEnum Code);
}
```

Then you could define the derived classes like this:

```
public sealed class Keyboard : InputDevice<KeyboardButton, KeyCode> {
    public override KeyboardButton GetButton(KeyCode Code) {
        // implementation here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Didn't consider to use two generic types

Answer (score 1):

Just declare `InputDevice<T>` abstract

```
public abstract class InputDevice<T>
{
    protected abstract void GetButton(System.Type type);
}
```

furthermore you can set `InputDevice<T>` as an inheritor of `IInputDevice` this will work too.

Comment: You don't need the blank constructor any more.