# C# - Override generic type constraints of generic abstract methods

Tags: c#, generics, overriding, abstract-methods

Is it possible to override generics constraints for abstract methods implementation?

Let me explain... normally I would do something like:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract class IData {}

    public abstract void DoSomething(IData data);
}

public class B : A
{
    public DataB : IData
    {
        public int ciao;
    }

    public override void DoSomething(IData data)
    {
        DataB d = data as DataB;

        if (d == null)
        {
             // print error or whatever...
             return;
        }

        int miao = d.ciao * 2;
        // do whatever with miao or d.ciao...
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public DataC : IData
    {
        public float arrivederci;
    }

    public override void DoSomething(IData data)
    {
        DataC d = data as DataC;

        if (d == null)
        {
             // print error or whatever...
             return;
        }

        int bau = d.arrivederci * 2f;
        // do whatever with bau or d.arrivederci...
    }
}
```

What I don't like is that I can pass to the `DoSomething` function an invalid parameter type.

I would want to be able to do something like

```
public class B : A
{
    public DataB : IData
    {
        public int ciao;
    }

    public override void DoSomething(DataB data)
    {
        int miao = d.ciao * 2;
        // do whatever with miao or d.ciao...
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public DataC : IData
    {
        public float arrivederci;
    }

    public override void DoSomething(DataC data)
    {
        int bau = d.arrivederci * 2f;
        // do whatever with bau or d.arrivederci...
    }
}
```

which of course is not possible.

For this reason I ended up doing something like:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract class IData {}

    public abstract void DoSomething<T>(T data) where T : IData;
}
```

The next step would be to make something like

```
public class B : A
{
    public DataB : IData
    {
        public int ciao;
    }

    public override void DoSomething<T>(T data) where T : DataB
    {
        int miao = d.ciao * 2;
        // do whatever with miao or d.ciao...
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    public DataC : IData
    {
        public float arrivederci;
    }

    public override void DoSomething<T>(T data) where T : DataC
    {
        int bau = d.arrivederci * 2f;
        // do whatever with bau or d.arrivederci...
    }
}
```

So, basically, override the generic constraint I did set in the parent's abstract generic method. Is there a way to achieve this?

Please note: I don't want to create a generic class but only a generic method that is able to get the right type of data per each different implementation of the base class.

Comment: This could not be valid: you've promised that `DoSomething` will accept any `IData` in `A`. You can't go and change your mind in `B` or `C` to only accept more derived types, even if constraints where variant in any way (which they're not). Consider carefully what kind of type safety (if any) you're really trying to achieve, here. Typically, this kind of design often means that you're setting up an inheritance hierarchy you actually don't want, but is better done through extension methods, concrete classes or (if really necessary) `new` methods and explicit downlevel casts in derived classes.

Comment: Try putting the type parameter on the `A` class instead of on the `DoSomething` method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force derived class to implement interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917929/force-derived-class-to-implement-interface)

Comment: In `public abstract class A()` the `()` is invalid. Can you correct the code to make it valid C#?

Comment: @JasperKent thank you very much  :)  sorry for the error, the original example was all methods and then I converted them to classes  :P now it should be ok

Comment: @devNull I asked the question because I wanted to avoid to make the entire class generic, so, I was trying to understand if it was possible to achieve what I wanted just having the generic method. The post you suggested me can be a solution IF I make the entire class generic, but, again, the question was about just having a method like that and not the entire class.

Comment: The language simply doesn't allow this. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0460

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what I'm trying to achieve is currently not possible in C#.
After waiting for a while to see if there was a workaround I decided to quote JasperKent's comment as the definitive answer:

The language simply doesn't allow this.
See: [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0460](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0460)

Answer (score 0):

apparently it's not supported as you coded. But you may try a different coding like this:

```
public abstract void DoSomething<T, TConstraint>(T data) where T : TConstraint;

....

public override void DoSomething<T, DataB>(T data){ //your code here; }
....

public override void DoSomething<T, DataC>(T data){ //your code here; }
```